# why is jqXHR.responseText returning my PHP file and not executing the script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I'm trying to simply execute an ajax request to my server. The request passes my form data to signUp.php where the information is then process. Then php will echo back a responseText to my jqXHR object and I print the alert. The problem is that my php file is being executed, rather the jqXHR.responseText is instead returning the my php file itself as if it were a text file. A sample php responseTest would look like ...

```
"<?php
 php code ...
  ?>"
```

Instead I want the responseText to return my echoes. The code is written bellow.

```
            var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("signUpForm"));
            $.ajax({
                url: "./cgi-script/signUp.php",
                type: "POST",
                xhr: function giveXmlHTTP(){
                    myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if(myXhr.upload){
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandler, false);
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                },
                success: function(data,statusText,jqXHR){
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                },
                data:formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

        }
```

Comment: How do you serve your PHP?

Comment: What happens when you load signUp.php in the browser? I would imagine that just shows the php source code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These generally happens when PHP does not gets parsed. So make sure you are running on the **SERVER** which is capable and configured to run PHP and are not *double clicking the HTML page*.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying that out. I will need to re-configure apache to get this to work. For some reason, I thought it should work on the fly. But my computer does run PHP. I thought that I could get away with it not running on apache, guess not.

Comment: @Mr.Student, IIS can run PHP, google that. You will find plenty of solutions.

Comment: I just said the hell with it and ran it on apache. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common causes for this problem are that you are missing the initial `<?php` and that your server has not been set up for PHP. My guess is that when you just visit `signUp.php` you'll find the same problem.